# Highlight the jQuery $ variable in Sublime Text 3 (build 3103)

Tags: sublimetext3, syntax-highlighting, sublimetext

In Feb 2016, the update to build 3103 broke a custom theme of mine, mostly in regard to Javascript. I really miss the ability to target the $, it seems that it's now under the scope:

`meta.function-call.with-arguments.js variable.function.js` when modifying the theme.

I want to know if there's a way to bypass or over-rule the $ sign, perhaps some REGEX or a way to add scope into the .tmLanguage file, so that I may color it differently from other "variable functions".

Comment: https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/javascript-syntax-highlighting-changes-in-3103/17328/12

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Until the unpaid/non-dev Sublime Text 3 is updated >= build 3106, follow these instructions to theme your $ variable in JavaScript or otherwise allow updated themes to function properly.

1. On your computer, go to `Sublime Text 3\Data\Packages` and make a new folder named "JavaScript", exactly that.
2. Visit https://github.com/sublimehq/Packages/blob/master/JavaScript/JavaScript.sublime-syntax
3. Copy that text, save as JavaScript.sublime-syntax in your new JavaScript folder. This will update the grammar to accept $ as its own scope.
4. You can now target variable.other.dollar.only.js and punctuation.dollar.js

**Modifying Your Theme**

Add this to your favorite theme if it hasn't been updated! Change the `foreground` to your liking.

```
<dict>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>jQuery $</string>
    <key>scope</key>
    <string>punctuation.dollar.js</string>
    <key>settings</key>
    <dict>
        <key>foreground</key>
        <string>#b3935cff</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
```