# Sublime text 3 theme - change color of $(this)

Tags: sublimetext3

I'm using Sublime Text 3 as my favorite editor. I use it mostly for javaScript and jQuery and I have found that it would be great if I could change the color of every instance of "$(this)" or at least "$".

How can I do this. I opened the theme, but I'm not sure what to put inside the Scope string tags...

Can anyone help?

Comment: You can use ScopeHunter for getting the scope https://github.com/facelessuser/ScopeHunter

Comment: It was a good hit, thanks. I used it for other scopes. But this one here fixed the issue completely: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35557523/highlight-the-jquery-variable-in-sublime-text-3-build-3103